# How to write more Pythonic Code

Tags: python, python-2.7, idioms

I started learning python today from the tutorial on the official site.

When reading about **filter(function, sequence)** i thought of making a function that returns if a number is prime to use it with the filter.

```
notDividedBy = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

def prime(num):
    """True if num is prime, false otherwise"""    
    copy = notDividedBy[:]
    check = True
    if num in copy:
        copy.remove(num)
    for x in copy:
        if num % x == 0:
            check = False
            break
    return check
```

The above code works in the shell.

My question is: Since i feel like although a solution, it is not the most elegant one, can anyone transform this code to something more python-like?(better structure? less lines?)

I believe it would help me for better understanding of the basics of the language.

The thing is, don't use any imports or anything, just simple staff.

Comment: Check out the Python section of this, too, for some good ideas http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing off the bat, if you are going to implement prime testing in this fashion, there's no reason to use an auxillary array

```
def prime(num):
    """True if num is prime, false otherwise"""    
    check = True
    #if num in copy:
    #    copy.remove(num)
    for x in range(2,x-1):
        if num % x == 0:
            check = False
            break
    return check
```

Comment: xrange is even better since it's a generator

Comment: @GoingTharn: In Python 3.x, `range()` is a generator and `xrange()` no longer exists.

Comment: i picked this answer because it was the closest to what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: @GregHewgill question is tagged as 2.7, I checked prior to commenting

Answer (score 4):

Creating many many copies of lists is not a particularly efficient way of doing things. Instead use the `xrange()` (Python 2.x) or `range()` (Python 3) iterator. Here's one (naive) way you could implement a primality test:

```
from math import sqrt

def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2: return False
    if n == 2: return True
    if not n % 2: return False #test if n is even

    #we've already remove all the even numbers, no need to test for 2
    #we only need to test up to sqrt(n), because any composite numbers can be
    #   factored into 2 values, at least one of which is < sqrt(n)
    for i in xrange(3, int(sqrt(n)) + 1, 2): 
        if not n % i:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this one:

```
def is_prime(num):
    return not any(num%i == 0 for i in xrange(2,num/2+1))

for i in xrange(10):
    print i, is_prime(i)
```

**Explanation**

start with:

```
(num%i==0 for i in xrange(2,num/2+1))
```

This is a generator expression.  I could have made it a list comprehension:

```
[num%i==0 for i in xrange(2,num/2+1)]
```

The list comprehension is equivalent to:

```
ll=[]
for i in xrange(2,num/2+1):
    ll.append(num%i==0)
```

The difference between the generator and the list comprehension is that the generator only gives up it's elements as you iterate over it -- whereas the list comprehension calculates all the values up front.  Anyway, from the above code, you can see that the expression generates a sequence of True's and False's.  True if the number can be divided by i and False otherwise.  If we generate a sequence of all False numbers, we know we have a prime.

The next trick is the `any` built in function.  It basically searches through an iterable and checks if any of the values is True.  As soon as it hits a `True`, it returns True.  If it gets to the end of the iterable, it returns `False`.  So, if the entire sequence is False (a prime number) then `any` will return `False`, otherwise it returns `True`.  This would be perfect for a `not_prime` function, but our function is `is_prime`, so we just need to invert that result using the `not` operator.

The benefit of using the generator expression is that it is nice and concise, but also that it allows `any` to return before checking every value which means that as soon as it finds a number that divides `num`, it returns instead of generating all `num/2` numbers.

Anyway, I hope this explanation is helpful.  If not, feel free to leave a comment and I'll try to explain better.

Comment: +1 for brevity; but maybe you should consider the OP is a newbie, so you should maybe elaborate/explain more! ;-)

Comment: @DonQuestion -- You're right.  I've added an explanation, but I fear we have lost the brevity of this answer (although the code is still brief:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 2 liner using filter().

```
def prime(num):
    """True if num is prime, false otherwise"""
    if num < 2:
        return False
    return len(filter(lambda x: num % x == 0, range(2, num))) == 0
```